# Playing a downloaded song

Tags: android

I'm new to android so I'm having a problem thinking of a solution. First thing I do is change activities to a different screen, and while in the activity I download a song. I then return to MainActivity which is a MediaPlayer activity. Now, I'm a little confused on activity lifecycles, if I return to MainActivity, and run:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
        File song = new File(path, "SpaceJam.mp3");
```

That's in my onCreate, so basically I'm asking does onCreate run every time you return to an activity?

Second, I have a play/pause button:

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_t);                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_t);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

The problem is, I don't want to do use:

```
mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

On my play button, because it'll reinitialize the song every time. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`That's in my onCreate, so basically I'm asking does onCreate run every time you return to an activity?`

No.  `onResume()` or `onStart()` would be good choices but you should read the Activity life cycle documentation and choose accordingly.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

`On my play button, because it'll reinitialize the song every time. What's the best way to go about doing this?`

To save the current position, e.g. in `onPause()`

```
Mediaplayer.pause();
length=Mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

To resume, e.g. in `onResume()`

```
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
Mediaplayer.start();
```